# Dash open tkinter file select dialog on click button

Tags: plotly-dash

I am trying to open a file dialog to select some local files. Apparently, Dash does not have this option build in, so I try to do it with tkinter. I find the Dash syntax very confusing with all these strange dependencies. When I run the example below, the file dialog opens as soon as I start the script, but not when I click the button. I desire the opposite behavior. The file selector dialog should open when I click the button and not when after starting the script.

```
from tkinter import Tk, filedialog

...

### Load files
@app.callback(
    Output('B_add-files', 'value'),
    [Input('B_add-files', 'n_clicks')],
    [State('files-check', 'value')] )
def select_files(n_clicks, options):
    if n_clicks is not None:
        root = Tk()
        root.withdraw()
        root.call('wm', 'attributes', '.', '-topmost', True)
        if 'by-dir' not in options:
            files = filedialog.askopenfilename(multiple=True)
            files = [abspath(i) for i in files]
            for i in files:
                assert isfile(i)
        else:
            dir_ = filedialog.askdirectory()
            if isinstance(dir_ , tuple):
                dir_ = []
            if len(dir_) != 0:
                files = glob(join(dir_, join('**', '*.mzXML')), recursive=True)
            else:
                files = []
        if len(files) != 0:
            mint.files += files
        root.destroy()
    return str(n_clicks)
```

This code now works most of the time. Only, if I click on the button multiple times, sometime the server stops and I get the error:

> Tcl_AsyncDelete: async handler deleted by the wrong thread

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code where you call or even reference `on_click`. Also, if you're trying to do this in a web server, are you aware that the dialog will only open on the display connected to the server, and not in a web browser?

Comment: Totally aware of that. I want to select local files. It is not a web-application.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you’re looking for the Upload component... https://dash.plot.ly/dash-core-components/upload

If not, then your Input dependency should be on the “n_clicks” attribute of your button, rather than on “children”: https://dash.plot.ly/dash-core-components/button

Comment: I am not looking for an upload component.